# Should I use a DAO pattern if I don't want full objects returned?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao

Basically I have to query an external database to my Java application, I am just given the queries to run, of which there are only a handful of basic selects e.g. Select x,y,z from Table.  No Updates/Deletes etc and I cannot create a connection pool to the database, I have to instantiate a new connection with each query as its multi-threaded.  My question is can I do this with a DAO pattern, if so can you advise how to implement it with regards to connection and service layers.  If DAO pattern is not advisable, what is a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

For you connection pool issue,you can visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

DAO pattern is used to separate low level data accessing API or operations from high level business services 
As you have mentioned you have to create new connection with each query as its multi-threaded , opening a database connection is an expensive operation.So you can use ORM like Hibernate for your operation and connection pool management.

Comment: Or OP could choose not to use Hibernate. No need to complicate things unnecessarily.